# Modify EF 6.x DbContext Generator to use connection string instead of .edmx

Tags: entity-framework-6, t4

I would like to generate EF POCO entities directly from my database using a connection string, but the templates that I can add to my project all expect me to have an .edmx file, which I do not. I can't seem to find out how to modify the template correctly to do this but I know it is possible. Any T4 template wizards out there that can help?

Answer (score -2):

In the solution explorer, you can add an EDMX. Right-click, add, class, and select ADO.NET Entity Data Model. You can then select "EF Designer from database" and VS will generate the POCO entities for you. They'll be tucked inside the EDMX, nested under the .tt file.

From there, it's easy to **manually** create the metadata files as partial classes of the generated entities, however I've never generated the metadata properties automatically. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx might get you there. If you find a better resource, let me know.

Comment: I do not want an .edmx file in my project. That is the point.